# Does adding twist to wing always decrease induced drag and what are its effect on parasite drag?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics

I am doing an assignment and one question was the effect of twist on drag. The first two options are increased induced drag and decreased induced drag respectively. The third option is increased parasite drag. I am confused b/w option 2 and 3.

Comment: I think what is missing from the question is the frame of reference for what part is fixed, and what part is twisted.  In other words, given an untwisted wing at a given AoA, twisting either the root up or the tip down will have opposite effects.  (*You might get brownie points for understanding from your professor if you ask for this clarification*)

Answer (score 3):

If you do a bad job twisting a wing, you can certainly make induced drag worse.

Twisting a wing should not have a significant effect on parasite drag.  If you have a very detailed parasite drag model, you might be able to calculate some difference, but to first order, no change.

Twist is also useful for manipulating the stall distribution -- inboard or outboard.  This is essential for handling qualities.

It also shifts the load distribution which can have a significant structural effect.